# shortest path algorithm from text input

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph-algorithm

I've been trying to do this shortest path problem and I realised that the way I was trying to it was almost completely wrong and that I have no idea to complete it.

The question requires you to find the shortest path from one point to another given a text file of input.

```
The input looks like this with the first value representing how many levels there are.

4  
14 10 15  
13 5 22  
13 7 11  
5

This would result in an answer of: 14+5+13+11+5=48
```

[image: Which represents a graph like this]

The question asks for the shortest path from the bottom left to the top right.

The way I have attempted to do this is to compare the values of either path possible and then add them to a sum. e.g the first step from the input I provided would compare 14 against 10 + 15. I ran into the problem that if both values are the same it will stuff up the rest of the working.

I hope this makes some sense.

Any suggestions on an algorithm to use or any sample code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See Dijkstra's_algorithm on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm) (or search on the web) for the general-purpose solution to finding shortest path between connected points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of a simple version of the algorithm is the following:

- define a list of **vertices** (places where you can stay) and **edges** (walks you can do)
- every vertex will have a list of edges connecting it to other vertices
- for every edge store the walk length
- for every vertex store a field with 1000000000 with the meaning "how long is the walk to here"
- create a list of "active" vertices initialized with just the starting point
- set the walk-distance field of starting vertex with 0 (you're here)

Now the search algorithm proceeds as

1. pick the (a) vertex from the "active list" with lowest `walk_distance` and remove it from the list
2. if the vertex is the destination you're done.
3. otherwise for each edge in that vertex compute the walk distance to the `other_vertex` as

   `new_dist = vertex.walk_distance + edge.length`
4. check if the new distance is shorter than `other_vertex.walk_distance` and in this case update `other_vertex.walk_distance` to the new value and put that vertex in the "active list" if it's not already there.
5. repeat from 1

If you run out of nodes in the active list and never processed the destination vertex it means that there was no way to reach the destination vertex from the starting vertex.

For the data structure in C++ I'd use something like

```
struct Vertex {
    double walk_distance;
    std::vector<struct Edge *> edges;
    ...
};

struct Edge {
    double length;
    Vertex *a, *b;
    ...
    void connect(Vertex *va, Vertex *vb) {
        a = va; b = vb;
        va->push_back(this); vb->push_back(this);
    }
    ...
};
```

Then from the input I'd know that for `n` levels there are `2*n` vertices needed (left and right side of each floor) and `2*(n-1) + n` edges needed (one per each stair and one for each floor walk).

For each floor except the last you need to build three edges, for last floor only one.

I'd also allocate all edges and vertices in vectors first, fixing the pointers later (post-construction setup is an anti-pattern but here is to avoid problems with reallocations and still maintaining things very simple).

```
int n = number_of_levels;

std::vector<Vertex> vertices(2*n);
std::vector<Edge> edges(2*(n-1) + n);

for (int i=0; i<n-1; i++) {
    Vertex& left = &vertices[i*2];
    Vertex& right = &vertices[i*2 + 1];
    Vertex& next_left = &vertices[(i+1)*2];
    Vertex& next_right = &vertices[(i+1)*2 + 1];
    Edge& dl_ur = &edges[i*3];   // down-left to up-right stair
    Edge& dr_ul = &edges[i*3+1]; // down-right to up-left stair
    Edge& floor = &edges[i*3+2];

    dl_ur.connect(left, next_right);
    dr_ul.connect(right, next_left);
    floor.connect(left, right);
}

// Last floor
edges.back().connect(&vertex[2*n-2], &vertex[2*n-1]);
```

NOTE: untested code

## EDIT

Of course this algorithm can solve a much more general problem where the set of vertices and edges is arbitrary (but lengths are non-negative).

For the very specific problem a much simpler algorithm is possible, that doesn't even need any data structure and that can instead compute the result on the fly while reading the input.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    int n; std::cin >> n;
    int l=0, r=1000000000;
    while (--n > 0) {
        int a, b, c; std::cin >> a >> b >> c;
        int L = std::min(r+c, l+b+c);
        int R = std::min(r+b+a, l+a);
        l=L; r=R;
    }
    int b; std::cin >> b;
    std::cout << std::min(r, l+b) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The idea of this solution is quite simple:

- `l` variable is the `walk_distance` for the left side of the floor
- `r` variable is the `walk_distance` for the right side

Algorithm:

1. we initialize `l=0` and `r=1000000000` as we're on the left side
2. for all intermediate steps we read the three distances:

   `a` is the length of the down-left to up-right stair

   `b` is the length of the floor

   `c` is the length of the down-right to up-left stair
3. we compute the `walk_distance` for left and right side of next floor

   `L` is the minimum between `r+c` and `l+b+c` (either we go up starting from right side, or we go there first starting from left side)

   `R` is the minimum betwen `l+a` and `r+b+a` (either we go up starting from left, or we start from right and cross the floor first)
4. for the last step we just need to chose what is the minimum between `r` and coming there from `l` by crossing the last floor

Comment: Thanks, this really helps out a lot. Reading that though I think i would have trouble reading that in from a text file, any suggestions for that?

Comment: You mean how to open a file and read data from the file? Then ask that. Note however that if this is the homework you've been asked today, I'd guess reading from a file was probably a few months ago. Do you really think you can understand months of stuff in one hour? Neo learning kung fu in the matrix is not how things work (for now, at least).

Comment: this isn't homework, i have no problem reading the data from the file, my problem is then turning that data into vertices and edges. I actually have no idea with graph theory, just trying to learn.

Comment: I've added some code about how to setup a possible data structure. Note that this algorithm solves a problem more general than the n-floors-with-two-staircases and it's thus sort of over-killing if all you need is to solve that very specific problem.

Comment: "int L = r+c < l+b+c ? r+c : l+b+c;", seriously?

Comment: @Maxime: Whoops. I wrote it in C and only later converted to C++. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Use a depth-first search and add only the minimum values. Then check which side is the shortest stair. If it's a graph problem look into a directed graph. For each stair you need 2 vertices. The cost from ladder to ladder can be something else.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "add only the minimum values"

Comment: From each subbranch sum the minimum value and then check if it's far away from the left and add the other value.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the vertexes during the DFS otherwise you'll fall into a loop at each level (when you change side).

Answer (score 1):

Assume your data file is read into a 2D array of the form:

```
int weights[3][HEIGHT] = {
  {14, 10, 15},
  {13, 5, 22},
  {13, 7, 11},
  {X, 5, X}
};
```

where X can be anything, doesn't matter.  For this I'm assuming positive weights and therefore there is never a need to consider a path that goes "down" a level.

In general you can say that the minimum cost is lesser of the following 2 costs:
1) The cost of rising a level: The cost of the path to the opposite side from 1 level below, plus the cost of coming up.
2) The cost of moving across a level : The cost of the path to the opposite from the same level, plus the cost of coming across.

```
int MinimumCost(int weight[3][HEIGHT]) {
  int MinCosts[2][HEIGHT]; // MinCosts[0][Level] stores the minimum cost of reaching
                           // the left node of that level
                           // MinCosts[1][Level] stores the minimum cost of reaching
                           // the right node of that level

  MinCosts[0][0] = 0; // cost nothing to get to the start
  MinCosts[0][1] = weight[0][1]; // the cost of moving across the bottom

  for (int level = 1; level < HEIGHT; level++) {
     // cost of coming to left from below right
     int LeftCostOneStep = MinCosts[1][level - 1] + weight[2][level - 1];
     // cost of coming to left from below left then across
     int LeftCostTwoStep = MinCosts[0][level - 1] + weight[0][level - 1] + weight[1][level];
     MinCosts[0][level] = Min(LeftCostOneStep, LeftCostTwoStep);

     // cost of coming to right from below left
     int RightCostOneStep = MinCosts[0][level - 1] + weight[0][level - 1];
     // cost of coming to right from below right then across
     int RightCostTwoStep = MinCosts[1][level - 1] + weight[1][level - 1] + weight[1][level];
     MinCosts[1][level] = Min(RightCostOneStep, RightCostTwoStep);

  }

  return MinCosts[1][HEIGHT - 1];
}
```

I haven't double checked the syntax, please only use it to get a general idea of how to solve the problem.  You could also rewrite the algorithm so that MinCosts uses constant memory, MinCosts[2][2] and your whole algorithm could become a state machine.

You could also use dijkstra's algorithm to solve this, but that's a bit like killing a fly with a nuclear warhead.

Answer (score 1):

My first idea was to represent the graph with a matrix and then run a DFS or Dijkstra to solve it. But for this given question, we can do better.

So, here is a possible solution of this problem that runs in O(n). `2*i` means left node of level `i` and `2*i+1` means right node of level `i`. Read the comments in this solution for an explanation.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct node {
    int lup; // Cost to go to level up
    int stay; // Cost to stay at this level
    int dist; // Dist to top right node
};


int main() {
    int N;
    scanf("%d", &N);

    struct node tab[2*N];


    // Read input.
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < N-1; i++) {
        int v1, v2, v3;
        scanf("%d %d %d", &v1, &v2, &v3);
        tab[2*i].lup = v1;
        tab[2*i].stay = tab[2*i+1].stay = v2;
        tab[2*i+1].lup = v3;
    }
    int v;
    scanf("%d", &v);
    tab[2*i].stay = tab[2*i+1].stay = v;


    // Now the solution:

    // The last level is obvious:
    tab[2*i+1].dist = 0;
    tab[2*i].dist = v;

    // Now, for each level, we compute the cost.
    for (i = N - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        tab[2*i].dist = tab[2*i+3].dist + tab[2*i].lup;
        tab[2*i+1].dist = tab[2*i+2].dist + tab[2*i+1].lup;

        // Can we do better by staying at the same level ?
        if (tab[2*i].dist > tab[2*i+1].dist + tab[2*i].stay) {
            tab[2*i].dist = tab[2*i+1].dist + tab[2*i].stay;
        }
        if (tab[2*i+1].dist > tab[2*i].dist + tab[2*i+1].stay) {
            tab[2*i+1].dist = tab[2*i].dist + tab[2*i+1].stay;
        }
    }

    // Print result
    printf("%d\n", tab[0].dist);

    return 0;
}
```

(This code has been tested on the given example.)

Comment: For a specific solution there's no need of any data structure at all. You can compute the result directly while reading the input. See my edited answer.